# Is it possible to disable the transition when using Navigator.push()?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, transition, navigator

How do I disable the default transition behaviour whilst using React Native?

Here is my code:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
    component: view
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm currently using the following code myself to disable transitions in certain situations when I don't want them. This comes from [a discussion](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1953#issuecomment-121145746) on the react-native repository.

```
let buildStyleInterpolator = require('buildStyleInterpolator');

var NoTransition = {
  opacity: {
    from: 1,
    to: 1,
    min: 1,
    max: 1,
    type: 'linear',
    extrapolate: false,
    round: 100,
  },
};

return  {
  ...Navigator.SceneConfigs.FloatFromLeft,
  gestures: null,
  defaultTransitionVelocity: 100,
  animationInterpolators: {
    into: buildStyleInterpolator(NoTransition),
    out: buildStyleInterpolator(NoTransition),
  },
};
```